# C# Entity Framework Fluent API define composite key for a navigation property that is not being hold in that class (one-sided in the other class)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET Core 6.

I have 2 classes like

```
public class Foo {
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar { 
    // Some other properties. But no reference to Class Foo.
    public string UniqueName { get; set; }
}
```

Now in fluent API I want to give Class Bar a composite primary key consisting of 'UniqueName' and of 'FooId' (but FooId only exists in the database, not in the class).

How Would I go about doing this?

I couldn't find anything on stack already but that may be because I didn't really know all that good how to search for it (look at how bad this post title is).

Comment: Why not just add FooId to the model class?

Comment: It would serve no point in the domain classes other than for configuring the relation, so I was hoping to avoid adding it.

Comment: Different philosophies I suppose. I've always held your ORM model classes should be a full representation of your database, and if you want a different set of abstractions, you should build that a layer up in your application

Comment: Yes different philosophies indeed. Never done or learned it in college that way.

Comment: There are of course different philosophies for different entity models - domain model, data model etc. But EF Core entities represent the data model, so you have to create them following data model rules. Create another set of entities representing domain model and following its rules, and map between the two where needed. EF Core for sure needs the data entity model mapped to the database.